# How to fix wordpress permissions which is installed inside a bitnami magento container?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have AWS lightsail, I installed Magento 2 using bitnami. i want to install WordPress too since the client would like to have a blog as well.

I  installed WordPress (not bitnami image) but located in magento bitnami installation directory. Such that the url would be `example.com/blog`

There's a permission problem, whatever I could can't fix it, for example can't install plugins,

`Installation failed: Could not create directory.`

I tried `chmod 755 -R  wp-content/` and the `plugins/` directory and I tried adding wordpress to apache group, and so many things. Nothing fixes it, I feel it's because it's located inside betnami's folder.

You know why is this happening?

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Could you please let us know more information about how you installed WordPress in that instance? We provide many different ways to install WordPress on top of a running instance (Bitnami WordPress module installer, deploy a PHP app manually on a running instance, ... )

Comment: @JotaMartos i downloaded it from WordPress.org and placed it inside Magento installation directory

Comment: @JotaMartos, thank you, you solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to [bitnami forum](https://community.bitnami.com/t/is-it-possible-to-install-wordpress-using-bitnami-cli-on-aws/68313/3), especially Jota, thank you!. I fixed the issue by using bitnami wordpress module alongside magento. Login to the server then do

```
wget https://bitnami.com/redirect/to/548719/bitnami-wordpress-5.2.1-0-module-linux-x64-installer.run

chmod 755 bitnami-wordpress-5.2.1-0-module-linux-x64-installer.run

sudo ./bitnami-wordpress-5.2.1-0-module-linux-x64-installer.run
```

The installer should ask you to specify bitnami installation folder: `/opt/bitnami`

the default username for mysql  on bitnami  is root and you can get the password by doing `cat bitnami_credentials`

That password is the default password for mysql and your wordpress account, that's why you should immediately change it. The wordpress installation would be located at example.com/wordpress, which is exactly what I need, not damaging magento installation, it will be fully working.